# what kind of error is this one in ubuntu 20.04 that happen while restarting?

Tags: 20.04, reboot

I've recently changed my OS to ubuntu 20.04 and don't know much about Linux systems yet. Well, the following screen showed up while restarting:

[Screen showing possible error after I tried to restart.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aY0lA.jpg)

I don't have a clue about what it means and what to do next. I would appreciate any suggestions for solving it without damaging the system.

Comment: I note an `umount` & "remounting / RO" -- meaning FS (file-system) errors were detected, the flip (from *RW* to *RO*) is to prevent dataloss, and I'd not boot it again, instead boot a 'live' system (eg. Ubuntu install media & use the "Try Ubuntu") and do a `fsck` (file-system check) which will check for errors and fix any. I'd also check your `fstab` (/etc/fstab or file system table) to ensure no errors are located there; being new you may not understand it, but date/time stamp should reflect last change. and it's likely fine.. `fsck` if it detects issues will likely fix your issue)

Comment: thank you very much! It was realy helpful. I'm studying it in order to apply it appropriately.